# Swagger give Structural errors

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am getting the following errors in openAPI 3.0:

```
Structural error at components.schemas.put_400.properties.errors
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: readonly
Jump to line 1613
Structural error at components.schemas.patch_400.properties.errors
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: success
Jump to line 1648
```

this the where the errors are occuring(for the first one):

```
"put_400": {
            "description": "Bad Request. Failed to validate the payload",
            "type": "object",
            "example": {
                "errors": [
                    "serialId: serialId is required"
                ],
                "success": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "errors": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "readonly": true
                },
                "success": {
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "example": false
                }
            }
        }
```

for 2nd one:

```
   "patch_400": {
                "description": "Bad Request. Failed to validate the payload.",
                "type": "object",
                "example": {
                    "message": "invalid character \\n in string literal",
                    "success": false
                },
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "readOnly": true
                    },
                    "errors": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "success": "false;" 
                    }
                }
            }
```

I could not find much on the internet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the 1st error, change `readonly` to `readOnly` (with uppercase O).

As for the 2nd error, I guess you need to change

```
"errors": {
  "type": "object",
  "success": "false;"
}
```

to

```
"success": {
  "type": "boolean",
  "example": false
}
```

as used in `put_400`.